# datetime data: missing daylight-savings transitions

Tags: time-series

I'm working with a data set that has date/time fields that are given in 'EET/EEST'.  In the raw data, the timezone is not specified, instead the datapoints are of the form: '2021-09-01 00:00:00'.
Given that the timezone has daylight-savings-time transitions, I would expect to see missing and duplicated date/times corresponding to the daylight savings on-set and off-set. However, there are no missing or duplicated hours in the data. What am I missing here? Is it possible that this is really local time? Or can I conclude that it is instead the time in terms of a fixed UTC offset?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking us "What instant in time does '2021-09-01 00:00:00' correspond to?"
That is, you're asking what the
[zone offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Summer_Time) is.

We don't know.
You didn't tell us about the dataset,
how it was acquired,
or how it was cleaned prior to you getting to see it.
If most hours have more than a hundred timestamped rows,
that would be quite a different situation from most days
having just a couple of rows -- hard to tell if an event
near 1:30am UTC was likely to even be reported as an observation.

If your dataset describes behavior that is independent
of Earth's rotation, like quasar brightness, then there's
nothing to be done except chat with the person who collected the data
and ask why they callously discarded the zone offset,
or sync the dataset with known good quasar observations.

If your dataset shows diurnal variation, such as
highway traffic congestion or ambient temperature readings,
then the problem is simple.
Let the data speak for itself.
Compute a measure of central tendency, perhaps median.
See if a step change occurs for the last Sundays of March and October.